# Before write jquery plugin, etc. slider i want to know about structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Before writing a jquery plugin I should start one on the jquery slideshow, etc. I want to learn about the structure of this plugin. thank you very much.

Comment: and your question is? this is not in [SO] format, neither clear enough

Answer (score 2):

There's many ways you could start out creating your own jquery plugin.  Obviously you should have a good understanding of the way jQuery works first, but assuming that the best place to start would be the following:

[jQuery's plugin authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

[A solid jQuery plugin tutorial](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html)

In addition to those downloading a few plugins and using them as inspiration to write the same sort of plugin is a great way to learn.

Good Luck!